# How can I use an object for request parameters in HTTP Interface @GetExchange like you can in controller?

Tags: java, spring

When defining controllers you can get query parameters into an object simply by adding it to the method signature like so

```java
public record PageRequest(Integer pageSize, Integer page) {}

@GetMapping("/articles/{type}")
List<Article> listArticles(@PathVariable String type, PageRequest req) {
  ...
}
```

But how do I get the PageRequest to map to query string in *Spring HTTP Interface* `@GetExchange`?

This does not work:

```java
@GetExchange("/articles/{type}")
List<Article> listArticles(@PathVariable String type, PageRequest req);
```

nor does this:

```java
@GetExchange("/articles/{type}")
List<Article> listArticles(@PathVariable String type, @RequestParam PageRequest req);
```

the only thing I have gotten working is:

```java
@GetExchange("/articles/{type}")
List<Article> listArticles(@PathVariable String type, @RequestParam Integer pageSize, @RequestParam page);
```

That sends a request like `GET /articles/red/?pageSize=10&page=4` which then get mapped to the PageRequest object in the controller.

It would be nice to have identical method signatures in both controller and client.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue, and it can be solved by expressing the value as a Map:

```
@GetExchange("/articles/{type}")
List<Article> listArticles(@PathVariable String type, @RequestParam Map<String, Integer> page);
```

and then `page` is a Map with "pageSize" and "page" keys.